# Форма связи с несколькими кнопками

Tags: javascript

Подскажите готовый скрипт или решение, как сделать форму обратной связи с несколькими кнопками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы не создавать для каждой кнопки свою форму, а можно было открыть одну форму (у меня в модальном окне) и отправить выбранный вариант на почту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Снова вернувшись к этому вопросу (и подучив js), решил использовать следующий вариант:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // первая кнопка
    $('.buttons-parent').on('click', '#button1', function() {
        $('#input-type-hide').val('new-value');
    });

    // вторая кнопка
    $('.buttons-parent').on('click', '#button2', function() {
        $('#input-type-hide').val('new-value');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="buttons-parent">
        <button id="button1">Заказать</button>
        <button id="button2">Заказать</button>
    </div>

    <form>
        <input type="hidden" id="input-type-hide" value="here">
        ...
    </form>
```

**Описание:**

Одна форма для всех кнопок, скрытая в модальном окне. В форме скрытый `input`. При клике на кнопку заказа, переписывается значение у скрытого `input` на соответствующее, которое далее пересылается с остальными полями формы.

Использовал событие:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ .delegate()

https://ruseller.com/jquery?id=126 (на русском)

Если сообщение читают опытные js-разработчики, хотелось бы услышать, насколько это решение является грамотным, и как можно его оптимизировать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Динамическое заполнение формы из значений в таблице или по дополнительным атрибутам кнопки. Например, так:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
        $("#val1").val($(this).parent().parent().children(":eq(0)").html());
        $("#val2").val($(this).parent().parent().children(":eq(2)").html());
  $("#val3").val($(this).attr('data-info'));
  $('.modal').show();
})

$('.close').click(function(){
  $('.modal').hide();
})
```

```css
.modal{
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Field 1</th>
      <th>Field 2</th>
      <th>Field 3</th>
      <th>Field 4</th>
      <th>Field 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A Item 1</td>
      <td>A Item 2</td>
      <td>A Item 3</td>
      <td>A Item 4</td>
      <td><button data-info='a'>Заказать</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B  Item 1</td>
      <td>B Item 2</td>
      <td>B Item 3</td>
      <td>B Item 4</td>
      <td><button data-info='b'>Заказать</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C  Item 1</td>
      <td>C Item 2</td>
      <td>C Item 3</td>
      <td>C Item 4</td>
      <td><button data-info='c'>Заказать</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D  Item 1</td>
      <td>D Item 2</td>
      <td>D Item 3</td>
      <td>D Item 4</td>
      <td><button data-info='d'>Заказать</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E  Item 1</td>
      <td>E Item 2</td>
      <td>E Item 3</td>
      <td>E Item 4</td>
      <td><button data-info='e'>Заказать</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal">
  <div class="close">Close</div>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="val1" id='val1'>
    <input type="text" name="val2" id='val2'>
    <input type="text" name="val3" id='val3'>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Делаете одну форму в модальном окне, но заполняете значения ее полей динамически, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки Заказать. Скрипт с jquery может выглядеть примерно так.

```
$("button_selector").on("click", buttonHandler());

function buttonHandler(e){
 var productId = e.target.data("productId");
 var modal = $("modal_form_selector");
 modal.find("#product").val(productId);
 modal.show();
}
```